# java.lang.NullPointerException error message

Tags: java, imageicon

```
ImgSet[0] = new ImageIcon("bandeira-portugal.png",
                            "Portugal");
ImgSet[1] = new ImageIcon("south_korea-32.png",
                            "South_Korea");
ImgSet[2] = new ImageIcon("China-icon.png",
                            "China");
ImgSet[3] = new ImageIcon("Japan.png",
                            "Japan");
```

This is my code for the image icons. I am getting the error message "*java.lang.NullPointerException*"!
Can you please tell me how to fix it?
My picture files are in the program folder!

Yes I did set the variable *ImgSet* if that's got anything to do with it.

```
private Icon[] ImgSet;
```

Comment: please show us the stacktrace and more code.

Comment: Is your `ImgSet` array initialised?

Comment: ImgSet have the 3 images.so null pointer exception will be thrown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your array first. Thats all:)

```
private Icon[] ImgSet = new Icon[4];
```

Remember that you cannot change arrays length, after you initialize it, so select a good size, in this example it is 4.
If your collection is dynamic (you will add more elements, depending on runtime), change it to list, or set. Remember that arrays are fast, but their size is not editable.

Answer (score 0):

You're just ***declaring*** `ImgSet` variable by doing:

```
private Icon[] ImgSet;
```

To **initialize** you should do something like:

```
private Icon[] ImgSet = new Icon[n];
```

Where `n` should be an initialized `int` or `Integer`.

You may way to use something like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instances from the `java.util` package.

Comment: Welcome, glad you achieved it. New to Java uh?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget to initialize your array before.

Try this

```
ImageIcon[] ImgSet = 
{
   new ImageIcon("bandeira-portugal.png", "Portugal"),
   new ImageIcon("south_korea-32.png", "South_Korea"),
   new ImageIcon("China-icon.png", "China"),
   new ImageIcon("Japan.png","Japan")
};
```

Doubts: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html